# SSH remote forwarding fails for root user

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, openssh, sublime-text-3, sockets

I'm using remote forwarding for Sublime (`rmate`) using the following configuration in my (local) `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host host
User user
Hostname hostname
RemoteForward /home/user/.rmate.socket localhost:52698
```

This works successfully for non-root users:

```
debug1: Remote connections from /home/user/.rmate.socket:-2 forwarded to local address localhost:52698
...
debug1: remote forward success for: listen /home/user/.rmate.socket:-2, connect localhost:52698
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

However, when I try changing it to `User root`, it no longer works even when I change `RemoteForward` to `/root/.rmate.socket`, `/tmp/.rmate.socket`, *etc.*:

```
debug1: Remote connections from /root/.rmate.socket:-2 forwarded to local address localhost:52698
...
debug1: Remote: Server has disabled port forwarding.
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen /root/.rmate.socket:-2, connect localhost:52698
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen path /root/.rmate.socket
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

But, this works for `root` when using a remote port instead of a socket file:

```
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:52698 forwarded to local address localhost:52698
...
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 52698, connect localhost:52698
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

Is this the default behavior for the `root` user? Can I make it work for `root` as well?

Comment: Does `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contain `Match User root` and `AllowStreamLocalForwarding …`? What is this fragment exactly?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no, there is no ```AllowStreamLocalForwarding``` block. i'm using CentOS 7 btw.